# Symmetrizing bones only symmetrizes one single bone

Tags: rigging, bones

i'm new to blender as a whole and i was trying to dip my toes into rigging, thing is, the symmetrize button only symmetrizes the control point bone at the knee

[image]

I tried rotating it, selecting different bones, even closing blender and opening it again, what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your bones named correctly? Only bones with Blender's naming convention will symmetrize. From the docs:

> If you have a bone that has a copy on the other side (a pair), like an
> arm, give it one of the following separators:
>
> Left/right separators can be either the second position “L_calfbone”
> or last-but-one “calfbone.R”.
>
> If there is a lower or upper case “L”, “R”, “left” or “right”, Blender
> handles the counterpart correctly. See below for a list of valid
> separators. Pick one and stick to it as close as possible when
> rigging; it will pay off.
>
> Examples of valid separators:
>
> (nothing): handLeft –> handRight
>
> “_” (underscore): hand_L –> hand_R
>
> “.” (dot): hand.l –> hand.r
>
> “-” (dash): hand-l –> hand-r
>
> ” ” (space): hand LEFT –> hand RIGHT

Note also:

> If the side of the bone cannot be determined, it will be ignored.